# How to use custom template for label in selected option in v-select?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-select

I have used `<template slot="option" slot-scope="option">` for custom label in v-select. Here, everything is working fine. The custom label is working fine when the options are opened as shown in the screenshot here: http://prntscr.com/kluu7p but the custom label is not working for selected option or when the select is closed: http://prntscr.com/kluudy . 
Here is the snippet I have used to use custom template in v-select:

```
<v-select @input="updateShippingCharge"
    v-model="selected"
    :options="options">
    <template slot="option" slot-scope="option">
        <span :class="['flag-icon', `flag icon-${option.value.toLowerCase()}`]"></span>
            {{ option.label }}
    </template>
</v-select>
```

Comment: you might find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984126/vue-2-select2-custom-template-for-label helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Add another template with attribute **slot="selected-option"**.

```
<template slot="selected-option" slot-scope="option"></template>
```

The final code should look like this:

```
<v-select @input="updateShippingCharge"
    v-model="selected"
    :options="options">
    <template slot="option" slot-scope="option">
        <span :class="['flag-icon', `flag icon-${option.value.toLowerCase()}`]"></span>
            {{ option.label }}
    </template>
    
    <template slot="selected-option" slot-scope="option">
        <span :class="['flag-icon', `flag icon-${option.value.toLowerCase()}`]"></span>
            {{ option.label }}
    </template>
</v-select>
```